Share Excel File to Power Macros Spreadsheet
I hope someone already has done something similar as I am hitting a wall.
In the team we have a spreadsheet on local network where we list part with some parameters; The data is used to run Macros to produce pdf drawings i.e. combine image with a table.
The problem is that only one person can use it at the time and also we would like to put it online for remote access.
How may I make the datasheet sharable and still be able to run macros on desktop?
For ref, I am design engineer and only self learning some programming, I have not delved into databases. Spreadsheet is under 20000 rows;
What I tried so far:

Simple, just drag the macro spreadsheet to sharepoint; One can open the spreadsheet on desktop app and run macro. Once macro is run, other user's spreadsheet become read only as it could not be merged anymore
Place the input side to SharePoint; Then Power query the data to a desktop spreadsheet with macros. i.e. a desktop spreadsheet just to view and run macros. The problem, it take 1 - 5 minutes for changes on online spreadsheet then appear on the power query data. (The refresh take 10-20s; but it keep bringing old version entries until 1-5min later, must be a feature within the Microsoft SharePoint). That is rather too long as do many edits and want to see the results quickly.
Do I need to go database route; if so what would you recommend (e.g. dataverse, azure SQL?), ideally we still want to use excel for inputting multiple rows quickly? How quick the refresh may be?


First of all, thats really brilliant to solve the problem as a self-learnt programmer !!
Now, that's a common issue with collaborative spreadsheets involving macros.
I would suggest the following:
Since your data is under 20,000 rows, moving the data to a database like Azure SQL/DataVerse will provide you an scalable solution. These also allow quick access, updates, and better concurrency than sharepoint or Excel. You can continue using Excel as front end to input data, and link your excel to the database, Macros in excel will still run on desktop, pulling the latest data from the database. This will save from macros locking the database and thus multiple users can access and edit the data simultaneously.
Refresh rate- when connected to these databases refresh becomes instantaneous unlike those with sharepoints.
You can access these databases at your ease remotely.
Hope that answers your questions !

Depending on your situation, if you are able to place a file resource on a web server, you could have the parameters as a CSV or JSON file available via web server. For remote access, you'll probably end up wanting a web endpoint anyway.
If you do this then you're creating a web API, so instead of making a macro that points to 'myserver.com/resources/csv/xyz.csv', go the extra step of setting up a URL that makes sense, API-wise, such as 'myserver.com/MyProductName/API/v1/GetParameters' This will protect you in the future. Maybe as things grow...

there will be different authentication needs,
the data should be returned from a database instead of simply returning a file's contents,
???

